# ClientDetailsService is deprecated

Tags: spring-security, migration, deprecated, authorization-server

Since Spring Security OAuth has reached it's End-of-Life, I'm having trouble implementing some classes in Spring's new "Spring Security" + "Spring Authorization Server".

Does anybody know what replaces "ClientDetailsService"? I've got an "Application Management" app that handles multiple clients authorization setup. I see that it's deprecated and the documentation page (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/site/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientDetailsService.html) is telling me to check out the OAuth2 Migration Guide, but that guide does not answer my question.

Any advice would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While not everything may be a 1-to-1 match between the two, the [`RegisteredClientRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#registered-client-repository) is what you're looking for (also see [api docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/RegisteredClientRepository.html)).